# How to convert html documents to pdf using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

I’m working on creating document forms using vanilla JavaScript with HTML layout. I want to allow users to download the form view in PDF format.

So I’m thinking to have a download button in the UI and once user clicks the button, I want the form to be downloaded as PDF format.

What’s the best way to achieve that?

Additionally, I've used `jsPDF` but *korean* font is not working properly.

### index.html

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="ko">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>Vanilla JS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="temp">
        <h1>안녕하세요</h1>
        <ul>
          <li>사과</li>
          <li>오렌지</li>
          <li>바나나</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <button id="hi">다운로드</button>
    </body>
  </html>
```

### app.js

```js
import {jsPDF} from 'jspdf';
import { font } from './font';

const button = document.querySelector('#hi');
const koreanTextDiv = document.querySelector('#temp');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const doc = new jsPDF();

  doc.html(koreanTextDiv, {
    callback (doc) {
      // setting language
      doc.addFileToVFS('NanumGothic-Regular-normal.ttf', font);
      doc.addFont('NanumGothic-Regular-normal.ttf', 'NanumGothic-Regular', 'normal');
      doc.setFont('NanumGothic-Regular');
      doc.setLanguage('ko-KR');
      doc.save();
    },
    fontFaces: [{
      family: 'NanumGothic-Regular',
      src: ["/NanumGothic-Regular.ttf"]
    }]
  })
});
```

### Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the underlying html2canvas, which doesn't have access to the font. You need to include it in your css, which should allow html2canvas to pick it up.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'NanumGothic-Regular';
    src: url('/fonts/NanumGothic-Regular') format('ttf');
}

body {
    font-family: 'NanumGothic-Regular';
}
```

You can confirm that the issue is not with jsPDF by passing text rather than html (which will then use jsPDF directly):

```
doc.addFileToVFS('NanumGothic-Regular.ttf', font);
doc.addFont('NanumGothic-Regular.ttf', 'NanumGothic-Regular', 'normal');
doc.setFont('NanumGothic-Regular');
doc.setLanguage('ko-KR');
doc.text("안녕하세요", 10, 10);
doc.save();
```

Comment: jsPDF is not vanilla js and requires add an external library which may not be allowed on your project